# Why is unique=True not enforced when using create()?

Tags: python, django, django-models

I have a model with a unique charfield:

```
class EmailTemplate(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField('Name', 
                            max_length=255,
                            help_text=_("e.g: 'welcome_email'"),
                            unique=True)
```

When I create 2 models with the same `name` in Django's admin interface, I get the expected error: `Email Template with this Name already exists.`.

However, if I do this programmatically I do not:

```
>>> EmailTemplate.objects.create(name='test_1')
<EmailTemplate: test_1 >
>>> EmailTemplate.objects.create(name='test_1')
<EmailTemplate: test_1 >
```

What am I missing? I thought `unique` was a db-level constraint?

Comment: Are you sure the migrations are applied to the DB?

Comment: @JPG yes, but also if it's showing the error in the admin console it has to be  applied

Comment: @alias51 not really no, Django also performs validation itself for uniqueness, so that is just a direct effect of the field having the constraint declared. You likely haven't applied the migrations (run `python manage.py makemigrations` and `python manage.py migrate`) causing your DB to not have the constraint.